# WPF ViewModel HashCode

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel that has a hierarchical collection of elements:

```
public class TestViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestElement> _testElementItemsSource;
    private TestElement _testElementSelectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<TestElement> TestElementItemsSource
    {
        get { return _testElementItemsSource; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._testElementItemsSource, value); }
    }

    public TestElement TestElementSelectedItem
    {
        get { return _testElementSelectedItem; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._testElementSelectedItem, value); }
    }
}

public class TestElement : BindableBase
{
    private Guid _id;
    private string _caption;
    private ObservableCollection<TestElement> _children;

    public Guid ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._id, value); }
    }

    public String Caption
    {
        get { return _caption; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._caption, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestElement> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._children, value); }
    }
}
```

When changing the 'Caption' property of any 'Child' element, anywhere in hierarchy - is there a way to get some HashCode for the whole TestViewModel, to indicate that the TestViewModel become dirty/modified?

Comment: This is known pattern - http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/dirty-flag.html, but in ViewModel migth be not appropriate since WPF not always calls Property setters explicitly so code in setter might not be executed during property change, so take this into account

Comment: The hash code of the view model does not change when a child changes, you can check this from your code using this.GetHashCode(). It only changes with a new object creation. I think you will need to create a new property, called IsModified for example, and changing it when needed.

Comment: And don't rely on GetHashCode, it will be misleading in your case since designed for other purposes in the first place

Comment: you could use the PropertyChanged event to set the IsDirty flag in a new baseclass (derived from bindablebase)

Comment: First: hookup a property changed of each element in Children in viewmodel. Then on change of caption property get hashcode of Viewmodel in viewmodel handler